# Dryscrape: scrape child node data from parent node list using xpath

Tags: python, web-scraping, dryscrape

I was trying to scrape http://quotes.toscrape.com/ using dryscrape and python for learning purpose. I was able to get all divs with class="quote". Would like to loop through the list of divs with class="quote" and get multiple data from this parent element using xpath.

```
import dryscrape
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
session = dryscrape.Session()
url = 'http://quotes.toscrape.com/'
print 'Visiting the URL...'
session.visit(url)
print 'Status: ', session.status_code()
for div in session.xpath("//div[@class='quote']"):
    # please help me to scrape author and quote for each div elements
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can loop through each xpath elements and those will be objects having the content of individual elements. Each objects will have methods to get the data.

```
import dryscrape
session = dryscrape.Session()
url = 'http://quotes.toscrape.com/'
print 'Visiting the URL...'
session.visit(url)
print 'Status: ', session.status_code()
for div in session.xpath("//div[@class='quote']"):
    print "Quote: ", div.at_xpath(".//span").text()
    print "Author: ", div.at_xpath(".//small").text()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'http://quotes.toscrape.com/'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
for div in soup.findAll("div", {"class": "quote"}):
  print('Quote : ' + div.find('span').get_text())
  print('Author : ' + div.find('small').get_text())
```